# Android: xml layout issue

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I'm sure it must be a little issue but I'm not able to make it work. I had a xml with two columns (weights: 5 & 1 as you can see in the table.xml) that worked perfectly. Now, I have add another one with the header and the data is not being placed in two columns with the weights as before and it is being placed all together, except for the header that works fine.

I do not want to put fix width values so I'd like a solution with the weight way.

Here are the two xml I'm using:

header.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/header"
          xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:orientation="vertical"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_width="fill_parent">
<!-- Header -->
<LinearLayout android:background="#1d688f"
              android:paddingTop="6dip"
              android:paddingBottom="6dip"
              android:paddingLeft="6dip"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent">

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="gone"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/paiseur"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/pais"/>

    <TextView 
        android:id="@+id/cantidadeur"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:text="@string/total" />

</LinearLayout>

<!-- List Divider -->
<View android:layout_width="fill_parent"
      android:layout_height="5dip"
      android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

<!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_weight="6">

    <ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
              android:layout_height="fill_parent"
              android:layout_width="0dp"
              android:layout_weight="6">
    </ListView>

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And the one for the list, table.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:paddingTop="6dip"
android:paddingBottom="6dip"
android:paddingLeft="6dip"
android:layout_weight="6"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/pid"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:visibility="gone"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/paiseur"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="5"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

<TextView 
    android:id="@+id/cantidadeur"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:textSize="20sp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have tried to change the width to 220dp of paiseseur in the table.xml and it indeed separate the coulmns but I'd like to have with weight as in the header.

I add the code just in case it has something to do:

```
setContentView(R.layout.header);
ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                        Verpaiseur.this, paisesList,
                        R.layout.table, new String[]{TAG_PID, TAG_PAIS, TAG_TOTAL},
                        new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.paiseur, R.id.cantidadeur});
lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

try this. This will help you.

```
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
          android:layout_width="wrap_content"
          android:layout_height="0dp"
          android:layout_weight="6">

<ListView android:id="@android:id/list"
          android:layout_height="fill_parent"
          android:layout_width="match_parent">
</ListView>
```

Comment: Sadly, the result is the same, both columns paiseur and cantidadeur are still together

Answer (score 0):

You've not set the width to 0dp at all places where you've used weight. Sometimes this causes garbage output in layouts if missed. Try setting width to 0dp every where you've used weight and see if that fixes your problem.

One example where you've not done it is this:

```
 <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
 <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/layout"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="fill_parent"
 android:layout_weight="6">
```

Check if the same thing is there else where.

Comment: Tried and not working I still have the problem with the table.xml when I put the data coming from the adapter

Answer (score 0):

try this one , as you have not given orientation to layout it cause error,
***without using `weightSum` you will not get proper solution and if you get that than it will not be applicable to all other devices***.

**header.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <!-- Header -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#1d688f"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="6dip"
        android:paddingLeft="6dip"
        android:paddingTop="6dip"
        android:weightSum="7">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/pid"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="1"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:visibility="visible" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/paiseur"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="5"
            android:text="pais"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/cantidadeur"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:text="total"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <!-- List Divider -->
    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="5dip"
        android:background="?android:attr/listDivider" />

    <!-- ListView (grid_items) -->
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="6">

        <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="6"></ListView>

    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

**table.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/header"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="7">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/pid"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="1"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/paiseur"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="paiseur"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/cantidadeur"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="cantidadeur"
        android:textSize="20sp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Same result, header showing perfect but not the data for the second xml

Comment: do you want to set data in second xml ? @IvánGonzalo

Comment: Yes, what I do is this: setContentView(R.layout.header); ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);
                    SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(
                            Verpaiseur.this, paisesList,
                            R.layout.table, new String[]{TAG_PID, TAG_PAIS, TAG_TOTAL},
                            new int[]{R.id.pid, R.id.paiseur, R.id.cantidadeur});
                    lv.setAdapter(adapter); I set the values to table.xml

Comment: still showing all the columns together without taking into account the weight

Comment: i have tried in my code and to me , its showing all three separate and proper. how than it changes in yours. @IvánGonzalo

Comment: I have copied and pasted both xml from your post and I'm getting all together, it is crazy!!. I have added the code just in case it has something to do

Comment: it is displaying me in proper way than what changes you want in it in .xml? @IvánGonzalo

Comment: The header is OK, the problem is with the data coming from the adapter that is not respecting the weight of the columns and it is being showed with any separation unless I put fix width for the TextView which I do not want

Comment: data will not move out of weight given to textviews. it will never change after given weight every text will set within that textview only@IvánGonzalo

Comment: It must be as you say but it is not working for me, it is like the width of the table.xml is not being consider as all the screen width